# Automating the import/export using Checkout App or Checkoutapp

Tags: e-commerce, checkout

We are looking at using Checkout App for a retail store that integrates with an existing website.

I am having a hard time finding any real docs on any of the process, as they are all sort of wizards in the app.

Does anyone have experience with this software as far as automating the importing/exporting of products and ledgers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the developers, you can do this at your own risk by directly accessing the postgresql DB that stores the products. but they warned that it is not recommended.

in short, the answer to this is no. you have to do a manual import of your data every time.